# Удалить из строки слеши

Tags: php, строки

есть строка

```
image\\/product_images\\/promyishlennyie-privyazi\\/Vento\\/profi-master-v2_vnt_050.jpg
```

не могу разобраться как удалить из нее все последовательности "\", пробовал через trim($path,'\') - ничего..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php)

```
$str = 'image\\/product_images\\/promyishlennyie-privyazi\\/Vento\\/profi-master-v2_vnt_050.jpg';
$str = str_replace('\\', '', $str);

echo $str;
```

Comment: спасибо, добрый человек, помогло. не подумал что в таком ключе можно решить вопрос) как станет доступно - ткну галочку Вам

Answer (score 1):

[stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.stripslashes.php)

```
echo stripslashes('image\\/product_images\\/promyishlennyie-privyazi\\/Vento\\/profi-master-v2_vnt_050.jpg');
```

[Пример на 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Jlajnc)